# How to find column where is punctation mark as a single value in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have DataFrame like below:

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3
-----|------|--------
abc  | P    | 123
b.bb | ,    | 22
  1  | B    | 2
...  |...   | ...
```

And I need to find columns where is only punctation mark like !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~

So as a result I need something like below (only COL2, because in COL1 is also punctation mark, but there is with other values).

```
COL2 
-------
 P    
 ,    
 B   
...
```

Comment: You can use `regex` for such purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a regex with [`str.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html) and [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
import re

chars = '''!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~'''
pattern = f'[{re.escape(chars)}]'
# [!"\#\$%\&'\(\)\*\+,\-\./:;<=>\?@\[\]\^_`\{\|\}\~]

out = df.loc[:, df.astype(str).apply(lambda s: s.str.fullmatch(pattern).any())]
```

Or with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
out = df.loc[:, df.isin(set(chars)).any()]
```

Output:

```
  COL2
0    P
1    ,
2    B
```

Comment: It works perfect, best answer given thank you mozway :)

Comment: @dingaro you're welcome. I added an alternative that might be more efficient (but less flexible)

Answer (score 2):

```
punc = set("!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~")
df.loc[:, df.applymap(lambda x: set(x).issubset(punc)).any()]
```